# Can we convert MVC application to android app using PhoneGap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cordova, phonegap

Is there any way that you can convert the MVC web application into android app using any of the 3rd party tools like PhoneGap.

Comment: Who should answer this question if you don't tell details?

Comment: Asp.net MVC application with web api?